# SSRS Matrix table not showing all rows

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I utilize the matrix object, and the report is not pulling all data. I have about 49 clients, and only half of the clients are showing up on the report.  Is there a configuration that limits the number of records to display.
[image]

Comment: No - there is no configuration that would limit the number of records. There are filters where you can filter out records but they would not be set by default. There is also grouping on a table or matrix that could be preventing some records from showing. For example, if you wanted to show employees but Grouped them by Gender, only two records would show (the first male and the first female). Try using a table first to show your records and see if they have all of the records you want - if they don't then check you dataset, otherwise check your grouping on the matrix.

Comment: The report parameters are Start and End Date then Main Client (Parent Client) and a Client. A Parent Client can have multiple Clients. I have another version of the report which is using the regular TABLIX object, and I see all 50 clients, but when I tried to develop similar report replacing the TABLIX with a MATRIX the missing clients occurs which is puzzling me because I have no special filters for Client.

Comment: If you are **Group**ing by parent client, then only the number parents would show - even if you are displaying only sub-clients. Check the grouping on your row and column groups of the matrix.

Comment: Here is the step I did that created this issue. I added a matrix box, then I deleted the first row then I insert outside row above for headers and then added the fields. As far as functionality of the TABLIX and MATRIX object should be the same right? It only differs in aggregation of data?

Comment: Yes - the only difference between the table and matrix is that the table doesn't have a column grouping. If you're not going to use the **column** grouping in a table, try using a table to see if it comes out any differently.

Comment: Thank you for you assistance. I just found out that the issue was not from the .rdl template. It was coming from the SQL stored procedure that was written by our developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem! Here's the solution the I found:

Just remove the query from the dataset query designer, close it and add the same query. Now all rows will appear in your report!